# Array Data Binding in VueJS

Tags: arrays, laravel, vue.js, data-binding, v-model

I need help in making my checkboxes in an array format. I have these codes:

```
<form @keyup="validate">
 <div class="form-group">
  <thead>
   <th>Task Schedule</th>
   <th>Notify Me</th>
   <th>Email Me</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr v-for="(row, index) in tableData.data" :key="index">
    <td> {{ row.name }} </td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="notify" name="notify" :value="tasks.id" v-model="data.notify"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="email" name="email" :value="tasks.id"  v-model="data.email"></td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </div>
</form>
```

Not sure though about the v-model of my checkboxes. because if I check even just one checkbox, the other boxes also gets checked. I think I need to add **computed** as well but Im not sure what to code. Thanks

Comment: [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41821760/3634538).

Comment: Can you post the content of tableData so that it will be more clear

Comment: You want something more like ```v-model="notify[index]"``` and define your notify property as an array